# Admob não esta funcionado na unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, admob

Importei o plugin conforme [site da admob](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/games) , [link do plugin](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/releases/tag/2.3.1)

utilizei o seguinte código para teste

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class GoogleMobileAdsDemoHandler : IInAppPurchaseHandler
{
    private readonly string[] validSkus = { "android.test.purchased" };

    //Will only be sent on a success.
    public void OnInAppPurchaseFinished(IInAppPurchaseResult result)
    {
        result.FinishPurchase();
        GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript.OutputMessage = "Purchase Succeeded! Credit user here.";
    }

    //Check SKU against valid SKUs.
    public bool IsValidPurchase(string sku)
    {
        foreach(string validSku in validSkus) {
            if (sku == validSku) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    //Return the app's public key.
    public string AndroidPublicKey
    {
        //In a real app, return public key instead of null.
        get { return null; }
    }
}

// Example script showing how to invoke the Google Mobile Ads Unity plugin.
public class GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    private BannerView bannerView;
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
    private static string outputMessage = "";

    public static string OutputMessage
    {
        set { outputMessage = value; }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        // Puts some basic buttons onto the screen.
        GUI.skin.button.fontSize = (int) (0.05f * Screen.height);
        GUI.skin.label.fontSize = (int) (0.025f * Screen.height);

        Rect requestBannerRect = new Rect(0.1f * Screen.width, 0.05f * Screen.height,
                                   0.8f * Screen.width, 0.1f * Screen.height);
        if (GUI.Button(requestBannerRect, "Request Banner"))
        {
            RequestBanner();
        }

        Rect showBannerRect = new Rect(0.1f * Screen.width, 0.175f * Screen.height,
                                       0.8f * Screen.width, 0.1f * Screen.height);
        if (GUI.Button(showBannerRect, "Show Banner"))
        {
            bannerView.Show();
        }

        Rect hideBannerRect = new Rect(0.1f * Screen.width, 0.3f * Screen.height,
                                       0.8f * Screen.width, 0.1f * Screen.height);
        if (GUI.Button(hideBannerRect, "Hide Banner"))
        {
            bannerView.Hide();
        }

        Rect destroyBannerRect = new Rect(0.1f * Screen.width, 0.425f * Screen.height,
                                          0.8f * Screen.width, 0.1f * Screen.height);
        if (GUI.Button(destroyBannerRect, "Destroy Banner"))
        {
            bannerView.Destroy();
        }

        Rect requestInterstitialRect = new Rect(0.1f * Screen.width, 0.55f * Screen.height,
                                                0.8f * Screen.width, 0.1f * Screen.height);
        if (GUI.Button(requestInterstitialRect, "Request Interstitial"))
        {
            RequestInterstitial();
        }

        Rect showInterstitialRect = new Rect(0.1f * Screen.width, 0.675f * Screen.height,
                                             0.8f * Screen.width, 0.1f * Screen.height);
        if (GUI.Button(showInterstitialRect, "Show Interstitial"))
        {
            ShowInterstitial();
        }

        Rect destroyInterstitialRect = new Rect(0.1f * Screen.width, 0.8f * Screen.height,
                                                0.8f * Screen.width, 0.1f * Screen.height);
        if (GUI.Button(destroyInterstitialRect, "Destroy Interstitial"))
        {
            interstitial.Destroy();
        }

        Rect textOutputRect = new Rect(0.1f * Screen.width, 0.925f * Screen.height,
                                   0.8f * Screen.width, 0.05f * Screen.height);
        GUI.Label(textOutputRect, outputMessage);
    }

    private void RequestBanner()
    {
        #if UNITY_EDITOR
            string adUnitId = "unused";
        #elif UNITY_ANDROID
            string adUnitId = "INSERT_ANDROID_BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";
        #elif UNITY_IPHONE
            string adUnitId = "INSERT_IOS_BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";
        #else
            string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
        #endif

        // Create a 320x50 banner at the top of the screen.
        bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.Top);
        // Register for ad events.
        bannerView.AdLoaded += HandleAdLoaded;
        bannerView.AdFailedToLoad += HandleAdFailedToLoad;
        bannerView.AdOpened += HandleAdOpened;
        bannerView.AdClosing += HandleAdClosing;
        bannerView.AdClosed += HandleAdClosed;
        bannerView.AdLeftApplication += HandleAdLeftApplication;
        // Load a banner ad.
        bannerView.LoadAd(createAdRequest());
    }

    private void RequestInterstitial()
    {
        #if UNITY_EDITOR
            string adUnitId = "unused";
        #elif UNITY_ANDROID
            string adUnitId = "INSERT_ANDROID_INTERSTITIAL_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";
        #elif UNITY_IPHONE
            string adUnitId = "INSERT_IOS_INTERSTITIAL_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";
        #else
            string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
        #endif

        // Create an interstitial.
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);
        // Register for ad events.
        interstitial.AdLoaded += HandleInterstitialLoaded;
        interstitial.AdFailedToLoad += HandleInterstitialFailedToLoad;
        interstitial.AdOpened += HandleInterstitialOpened;
        interstitial.AdClosing += HandleInterstitialClosing;
        interstitial.AdClosed += HandleInterstitialClosed;
        interstitial.AdLeftApplication += HandleInterstitialLeftApplication;
        GoogleMobileAdsDemoHandler handler = new GoogleMobileAdsDemoHandler();
        interstitial.SetInAppPurchaseHandler(handler);
        // Load an interstitial ad.
        interstitial.LoadAd(createAdRequest());
    }

    // Returns an ad request with custom ad targeting.
    private AdRequest createAdRequest()
    {
        return new AdRequest.Builder()
                .AddTestDevice(AdRequest.TestDeviceSimulator)
                .AddTestDevice("0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF")
                .AddKeyword("game")
                .SetGender(Gender.Male)
                .SetBirthday(new DateTime(1985, 1, 1))
                .TagForChildDirectedTreatment(false)
                .AddExtra("color_bg", "9B30FF")
                .Build();

    }

    private void ShowInterstitial()
    {
        if (interstitial.IsLoaded())
        {
            interstitial.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            print("Interstitial is not ready yet.");
        }
    }

    #region Banner callback handlers

    public void HandleAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        print("HandleAdLoaded event received.");
    }

    public void HandleAdFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
    {
        print("HandleFailedToReceiveAd event received with message: " + args.Message);
    }

    public void HandleAdOpened(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        print("HandleAdOpened event received");
    }

    void HandleAdClosing(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        print("HandleAdClosing event received");
    }

    public void HandleAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        print("HandleAdClosed event received");
    }

    public void HandleAdLeftApplication(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        print("HandleAdLeftApplication event received");
    }

    #endregion

    #region Interstitial callback handlers

    public void HandleInterstitialLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        print("HandleInterstitialLoaded event received.");
    }

    public void HandleInterstitialFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
    {
        print("HandleInterstitialFailedToLoad event received with message: " + args.Message);
    }

    public void HandleInterstitialOpened(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        print("HandleInterstitialOpened event received");
    }

    void HandleInterstitialClosing(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        print("HandleInterstitialClosing event received");
    }

    public void HandleInterstitialClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        print("HandleInterstitialClosed event received");
    }

    public void HandleInterstitialLeftApplication(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        print("HandleInterstitialLeftApplication event received");
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Simplesmente não funciona no emulador requisitar o anuncio ele fecha já no aparelho físico não fecha mas não acontece nada.

no emulador fica assim

[image]

Comment: Bora procurar o problema. Em primeiro lugar, use um Ad Unit válido, o ad unit ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111 é específico para testes e funciona antes de publicar o app (um ad unit "quente" precisa estar ligado a um app já publicado). Realmente não sei se isto funciona no emulador, que é notoriamente problemático com AdMob, eu nem perco tempo com ele. Você tem como compartilhar um Zip do projeto todo algum lugar para poder carregar aqui?

Comment: @epx eu testei como chave válida, só que eu tirei, bom segue o link do projeto que crie para testar anúncios https://www.dropbox.com/s/uatj3g8t8a28ak1/Teste01.rar?dl=0

Comment: A única diferença maior que vi foi que eu uso um timer de alguns segundos antes de começar a criar o ad, porque se criar assim que levanta a UI tende a dar pau (o app não está num estado 100% carregado). Vou passar em privado um link com meu projeto cujo interstitial funcionou ate ser tirado do mercado.

Comment: Bem, parece não ter um mecanismo de msg privada no SO (realmente não sabia) então faça download de https://www.dropbox.com/s/y1s157frvci140q/exemplo.zip?dl=0 e avise quando tiver feito para invalidar.

Comment: @epx não entendi, baixe o exemplo é para implementar o anuncio nele e testar é isso?

Comment: Sim como funcionava para mim deve funcionar para você, se não o problema tende a ser no ad unit, não no código.

Comment: @epx sem sucesso se poder me enviar um com admob já configurado só eu colocar outra chave .